# Want to replace DXImageTransform to make FireFox/Chrome Compatible

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

The following piece of code does not work on FF and Chrome but works on IE. I want to replace this part to make sure it works on all browsers.

Anybody, any idea?

Code below:

```
<td width="50%"  style="FILTER: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(gradientType=1,startColorStr=#163866,endColorStr=#8bc9f3); HEIGHT: 38px;">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Want to replace DXImageTransform to make FireFox/Chrome Compatible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201520/want-to-replace-dximagetransform-to-make-firefox-chrome-compatible)

Answer (score 0):

I advise to take a look at this [page](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient/), you can see how to setup gradient in cross browser way.

in your case it would give something like

```
<td width="50%"  style="FILTER: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(gradientType=1,startColorStr=#163866,endColorStr=#8bc9f3); background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#163866), to(#8bc9f3)) -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #163866,  #8bc9f3);"  HEIGHT: 38px;">
```

Please note I have not tested.